# unban all command not responding

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make an unban all command in `discord.js` v13 with reactions but whenever I have 0 bans in the server, it does not send the message that we have 0 bans and also, when I click on a reaction, it does not respond with anything

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { parse } = require("twemoji-parser");
const JUGNU = require("../../../handlers/Client");
const { Queue } = require("distube");

module.exports = {
  name: "unbanall",
  aliases: ["allunban"],
  description: `....`,
  userPermissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
  botPermissions: ['EMBED_LINKS', "ADMINISTRATOR"],
  category: "Mod",
  cooldown: 5,
  inVoiceChannel: false,
  inSameVoiceChannel: false,
  Player: false,
  djOnly: false,
  

  /**
   *
   * @param {JUGNU} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {String[]} args
   * @param {String} prefix
   * @param {Queue} queue
   */
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, queue, interaction, com) => {
    // Code
    try {
            if(message.author.id == message.guild.ownerId) {
                const someembedlol = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RED")
                .setTitle(`Remove Bans`)
                .setDescription(`Please confirm that you wish to revoke all current server bans in this guild.\n\n**Note:** This process may take awhile, and cannot be easily stopped or un-done.\n\n**Do you still wish to continue?**\n✅ - Yes, remove all bans.\n❌ - No, cancel command.`)
                .setThumbnail(`${client.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})}`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({text: "copyright plusbot"})

                message.channel.send({ embeds: [someembedlol] }).then(balls => {
                    balls.react('✅').then(() => balls.react('❌'));
                    const johncena = (reaction, user) => {
                        return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.bot == false && user.id === message.author.id;
                    };
                    balls.awaitReactions({ johncena, max: 1, time: ms("1m")}).then(collected => {
                        const react23847= collected.first();
                        if(react23847.emoji.name === '✅') {
                            message.channel.send({ content: `Please Wait! We are beginning the process now...` }).catch(e => {})
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                
                                message.guild.bans.fetch().then(bans => {
                                    if (bans.size == 0) {message.channel.send({ content: "There are no banned users." }); throw "No members to unban."};
                                    bans.forEach(ban => {
                                        message.guild.members.unban(ban.user.id);                     
                                    })
                                }).then(() => console.log("Users are being unbanned.")).catch(e => console.log(e))

                            }, 6000);
                        }
                        if(react23847.emoji.name === '❌') {
                            return message.channel.send(`Cancelling update bans process...`).catch(e => {})
                        }
                    })
                }).catch(e => {if(client.config.debugmode) return console.log(e);});
            } else {
                message.channel.send({ content: `Only the guild owner may use this command...` }).catch(e => {});
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

    }
}
```

I don't get any error in the console. When I click on the reaction, it still doesn't give any error

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? Maybe try checking if you have the correct intents via https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ClientOptions.

Answer (score 0):

When the ban list is empty it will undefined hence not calling your function afterwards. Try using `if (message.guilds.bans.fetch()) {your code} else {error message}`